# MSACCESS - How to change the control display property of a table field using ALTER COLUMN

Tags: vba, ms-access, properties

I have a function that has to change a table field into a BIT type and i also want to set its control display property to listbox, so i tried like this but don't know how to continue..

```
Dim dbs As Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb

dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblStore " _
& "ALTER COLUMN Storage BIT"
```

Comment: Why bother with setting control type in table? Users should not interact with tables or queries and a listbox can't display in datasheet so this serves little purpose. Lookups in table are bad. Use whatever control you want when designing form. Can't be done with action SQL anyway, requires VBA and TableDefs.

Comment: Consider instead defining a validation rule or a foreign key relationship. Also, don't make users edit data in tables. Use forms.